# Doctrine_Record doesn't set PK in object after save()

Tags: php, sql, orm, doctrine

Per documentation, Doctrine_Record after saving should set id of newly created record
as object property. In my case, new record is created, but not value is set on object (while database has this new id value). What has caused this?

```
$user1 = new ModelUsers();
$user1->save();
echo "last insert id=" . $user1->UserId;
```

PS UserId is configured in Model class with  `'primary' => true, 'autoincrement' => true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using camel case syntax, which is used to access related items as in :

```
$object->Related->getId();
```

When accessing a Doctrine_Record properties, you should use one of those syntaxes :

```
$object['user_id'];
$object->getUserId();
$object->user_id; // note that this is NOT camel case, but lowercase with underscores
$object->get('user_id');
```